# When does the start-process get executed?

Tags: powershell, sccm, mdt

Basically I'm trying to return exit codes from start-process to the script so that MDT/SCCM can fail correctly if an installation fails.

Generically here is the code I'm using:

```
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $setupexe -ArgumentList $setupargs -Wait -Passthrough
Exit $proc.ExitCode
```

My question is when does the `Start-Process` get executed? When I define $proc or when I call `$proc.ExitCode`?

What I'm trying to do is use the exit code in a `if` statement without having to store that code in another variable (reduce code clutter).

```
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $setupexe -ArgumentList $setupargs -Wait -PassThru
if ($proc.ExitCode -ne 0) {Exit $proc.ExitCode}

$proc2 = Start-Process -FilePath $setupexe2 -ArgumentList $setupargs2 -Wait -PassThru
if ($proc2.ExitCode -ne 0) {Exit $proc.ExitCode}
```

vs

```
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $setupexe -ArgumentList $setupargs -Wait -PassThru
$procexit = $proc.ExitCode
if ($procexit -ne 0) {Exit $procexit}

$proc2 = Start-Process -FilePath $setupexe2 -ArgumentList $setupargs2 -Wait -PassThru
$procexit2 - $proc2.ExitCode
if ($procexit2 -ne 0) {Exit $procexit2}
```

I don't want the `Start-Process` to be called again just to kill the script and return the error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Start-Process` will start the process when you define `$proc` and won't move on to the next line until it exits since you have the `-Wait` parameter defined.

This line `if ($proc.ExitCode -ne 0) {Exit $proc.ExitCode}` will not cause the code to run again.

You could test this on your computer by running the code with a quick program like notepad and see when program appears.

```
$a = start-process notepad.exe -wait -passthru
$a.exitcode
```